# Random generator returning endless duplicates

Tags: php

I am trying to create a random string which will be used as a short reference number. I have spent the last couple of days trying to get this to work but it seems to get to around 32766 records and then it continues with endless duplicates. I need at minimum 200,000 variations.

The code below is a very simple mockup to explain what happens. The code should be syntaxed according to 1a-x1y2z (example) which should give a lot more results than 32k

I have a feeling it may be related to memory but not sure. Any ideas?

```
<?php

function createReference() {
    $num = rand(1, 9);
    $alpha = substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 0, 1);
    $char = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $charLength = strlen($char);
    $rand = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $rand .= $char[rand(0, $charLength - 1)];
    }
    return $num . $alpha . "-" . $rand;
}

$codes = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 200000; $i++) {
    $code = createReference();
    while (in_array($code, $codes) == true) {
        echo 'Duplicate: ' . $code . '<br />';
        $code = createReference();
    }
    $codes[] = $code;
    echo $i . ": " . $code . "<br />";
}
exit;
?>
```

**UPDATE**

So I am beginning to wonder if this is not something with our WAMP setup (Bitnami) as our local machine gets to exactly 1024 records before it starts duplicating. By removing 1 character from the string above (instead of 6 in the for loop I make it 5) it gets to exactly 32768 records.

I uploaded the script to our centos server and had no duplicates.

What in our enviroment could cause such a behaviour?

Comment: [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) is not good for actual randomness. Use [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) instead. You can also seed it as you wish using [`mt_srand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php). Even better would be [`random_int()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) but it's PHP7 only.

Comment: randomness does not guarantee uniqueness, regardless of collision probability. You need to handle uniqueness in your code

Comment: Why not use [uniqid](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)?

Comment: What you are trying to do relates to a school project I had to do a year ago. I did not have that many numbers that I needed so what B-and-P says is correct about uniqueness. But look into this for efficient randomizing. It's very handy https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

Comment: for random string try this http://guid.us/GUID/PHP

Comment: do both servers have php.ini? (i assume it does) maybe difference in setup there? Sounds like it could be a memory issue?

Comment: "The code should be syntaxed according to 1a-x1y2z (example)" - this result format is a given?

Comment: @Mauritz Swanepoel you could decrement the value if a duplicate is found and again find random character till 200000 records ri8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks overly complex to me. Let's assume for the moment you really want to create *n* unique strings each based on a single random value (rand/mt_rand/something between INT_MIN,INT_MAX).

You can start by decoupling the generation of the random values from the encoding (there seems to be nothing in the code that makes a string dependant on any previous state - excpt for the uniqueness). Comparing integers is quite a bit faster than comparing arbitrary strings.
mt_rand() returns anything between INT_MIN and INT_MAX, using 32bit integers (could be 64bit as well, depends on how php has been compiled) that gives ~2<sup>32</sup> elements. You want to pick 200k, let's make it 400k, that's ~ a 1/10000 of the value range. It's therefore reasonable to assume everything goes well with the uniqueness...and then check at a later time. and add more values if a collision occured. Again much faster than checking in_array in each iteration of the loop.
Once you have enough values, you can encode/convert them to a format you wish. I don't know whether the `<digit><character>-<something>` format is mandatory but assume it is not -> [base_convert()](http://docs.php.net/base_convert)

```
<?php
function unqiueRandomValues($n) {
    $values = array();
    while( count($values) < $n ) {
        for($i=count($values);$i<$n; $i++) {
            $values[] = mt_rand();
        }
        $values = array_unique($values);
    }
    return $values;
}

function createReferences($n) {
    return array_map(
        function($e) {
            return base_convert($e, 10, 36);
        },
        unqiueRandomValues($n)
    );
}

$start = microtime(true);
$references = createReferences(400000);
$end = microtime(true);
echo count($references), ' ', count(array_unique($references)), ' ', $end-$start, ' ', $references[0];
```

prints e.g. `400000 400000 3.3981630802155 f3plox` on my i7-4770. (The `$end-$start` part is constantly between 3.2 and 3.4)

Using base_convert() there *can* be strings like `li10`, which can be quite annoying to decipher if you have to manually type the string.